# Is this incremental parser a functor, if so how would `fmap` be implemented?

Tags: parsing, haskell, coroutine

I really hate asking this kind of question but I'm at the end of my wits here. I am writing an incremental parser but for some reason, just cannot figure out how to implement functor instance for it. Here's the code dump:

**Input Data Type**

Input is data type yielded by parser to the coroutine. It contains the current list of input chars being operated on by coroutine and end of line condition

```
data Input a = S [a] Bool deriving (Show)

instance Functor Input where
    fmap g (S as x) = S (g <$> as) x
```

**Output Data Type**

Output is data type yielded by coroutine to Parser. It is either a Failed message, Done [b], or Partial ([a] -> Output a b), where [a] is the current buffer passed back to the parser

```
data Output a b = Fail String | Done [b] | Partial ([a] -> Output a b)

instance Functor (Output a) where
    fmap _ (Fail s)    = Fail s
    fmap g (Done bs)   = Done $ g <$> bs
    fmap g (Partial f) = Partial $ \as -> g <$> f as
```

**The Parser**

The parser takes [a] and yields a buffer [a] to coroutine, which yields back Output a b

```
data ParserI a b = PP { runPi :: [a] -> (Input a -> Output a b) -> Output a b }
```

**Functor Implementation**

It seems like all I have to do is fmap the function g onto the coroutine, like follows:

```
instance Functor (ParserI a) where
    fmap g p = PP $ \as k -> runPi p as (\xs -> fmap g $ k xs)
```

But it does not type check:

```
Couldn't match type `a1' with `b'
  `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for
         fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> ParserI a a1 -> ParserI a b
       at Tests.hs:723:9
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> ParserI a a1 -> ParserI a b
      at Tests.hs:723:9
Expected type: ParserI a b
  Actual type: ParserI a a1
```

Comment: `ParserI` is not a functor.  No instance exists.

Comment: Oh X(  may I ask you to explain why? And how might I restructure it such that it is a functor? For example in Attoparsec.Incremental (depreicated), the coroutine has type similar to (c -> Input a -> Output a b), but I could not figure out what the c is there for

Comment: `fmap g p = PP $ \as k -> runPi p as (\xs -> fmap g $ k as)` <- that last `as` there was intended to be an `xs`, wasn't it?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes fixed it and the associated error message. Thanks!

Comment: Right. Now it makes sense (the error message). The problem is that you need to pass an `Input a -> Output a b` to `runPi p` as the second argument. But what you have, `k`, is an `Input a -> Output a c` (when `g`'s type is `b -> c`). You'd need some way to convert an `Input a -> Output a c` into an `Input a -> Output a b`. But you have nothing to create a `b` from a `c`. The type variable `b` occurs in a wrong position for `ParserI` to be made a `Functor`. That's what Philip JF said.

Comment: Do you definitely need the second argument to the `PP` constructor to be a function, or could you store that information some other way? This is clearly where the problem lies.

Comment: @AndrewC I am open to all possible designs. The current design is based off of Data.Attoparsec.Incremental: `newtype Parser r a = Parser { unParser :: S -> (a -> S -> IResult r) -> IResult r }, where S is product of a few ByteStrings (not sure what a is which really bugs me). But in general I'd like to explicitly describe the fact that operations on the buffer is passed off to a co-routine, which sends it to some output and yields back to parser.

Comment: Dan Fisher explained it.  I just always annotate variables with variances in my head.  Since it is the argument to a function `Input a -> Output a b` is in a contra-variant position.  Therefore `Output a b` is in a contra-variant position.  Since the second argument of that type is covariant, you have a `b` in a contra-variant location and can't have a functor.  Sorry.

Comment: You could have a `Difunctor`, though, one with both covariant and contravariant arguments. Something like `data ParserIC a b b' = PP { runPi :: [a] -> (Input a -> Output a b) -> Output a b' }` and `type ParserI a b = ParserIC a b b` might be bearable. The upshot is that if you want to change `b` to `c` you, by nature of your variances, need functions both `(b -> c)` and `(c -> b)`.

Comment: You might be interested in [arrow parsers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrow#Parser)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Philip JF declared, it's not possible to have an `instance Functor (ParserI a)`. The proof goes by variance of functors—any (mathematical) functor must, for each of its arguments, be either covariant or contravariant. Normal Haskell `Functor`s are always covariant which is why

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`
```

Haskell [`Contravariant` functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant) have the similar

```
contramap :: (b -> a) -> (f a -> f b)`
```

In your case, the `b` index in `ParserI a b` would have to be both covariant and contravariant. The quick way of figuring this out is to relate covariant positions to `+` and contravariant to `-` and build from some basic rules.

Covariant positions are function results, contravariant are function inputs. So a type mapping like `type Func1 a b c = (a, b) -> c` has `a ~ -`, `b ~ -`, and `c ~ +`. If you have *functions* in output positions, you multiply all of the argument variances by `+1`. If you have functions in *input* positions you multiply all the variances by `-1`. Thus

```
type Func2 a b c = a -> (b -> c)
```

has the same variances as `Func1` but

```
type Func3 a b c = (a -> b) -> c
```

has `a ~ 1`, `b ~ -1`, and `c ~ 1`. Using these rules you can pretty quickly see that `Output` has variances like `Output - +` and then `ParserI` uses `Output` in both negative and positive positions, thus it can't be a straight up `Functor`.

---

But there are generalizations like `Contravariant`. The particular generalization of interest is [`Profunctor`](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2011/07/profunctors-in-haskell.html) (or `Difunctor`s which you see sometimes) which goes like so

```
class Profunctor f where
  promap :: (a' -> a) -> (b -> b') -> (f a b -> f a' b')
```

the quintessential example of which being `(->)`

```
instance Profunctor (->) where
  promap f g orig = g . orig . f
```

i.e. it "extends" the function both after (like a usual `Functor`) and before. `Profunctor`s `f` are thus always mathematical functors of arity 2 with variance signature `f - +`.

So, by generalizing your `ParserI` slightly, letting there be an extra parameter to split the ouput types in half, we can make it a `Profunctor`.

```
data ParserIC a b b' = PP { runPi :: [a] -> (Input a -> Output a b) -> Output a b' }

instance Profunctor (ParserIC a) where
  promap before after (PP pi) = 
    PP $ \as k -> fmap after $ pi as (fmap before . k)
```

and then you can wrap it up

```
type ParserI a b = ParserIC a b b
```

and provide a slightly less convenient mapping function over `b`

```
mapPi :: (c -> b) -> (b -> c) -> ParserI a b -> ParserI a c
mapPi = promap
```

which really drives home the burden of having the variances go both ways---you need to have bidirectional maps!

Comment: As usual, once you've got them in your brain they start to show up everywhere. Glad my example helped! :)

Comment: So since this is not a functor, there's no way to make an applicative out if it either? And is it also not possible to implement alternative and monad instances? Or is there some sort of equivalent construct over product categories?

Comment: You can make an `Applicative`, `Alternative`, `Monad` out of only the last parameter, `instance Applicative (ParserIC a b)` and that may be enough depending on what you need. I don't know if there are natural generalizations of those to use both parameters.